# Possible to add a column to an ActiveRecord model that is a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I can easily create a scaffold or model in Rails with a field that is a reference (foreign key) to another model:

```
rails g model Cat owner:references
rails g scaffold Cat owner:references
```

But I can't seem to do the same for adding a column in a migration:

```
rails g migration AddOwnerToCats owner:references
```

What the above does is produce a migration file like this:

```
class AddOwnerToCats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cats, :owner, :references
  end
end
```

And when I try and run it with `rake db:migrate`, I get this:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "references": syntax error: ALTER TABLE "cats" ADD "owner" references
```

So is there a way to add a column that is a reference to another model? Or do I just have to do:

```
rails g migration AddOwnerToCats owner_id:integer
```

And then go into the migration and add an index for `owner_id`?

Comment: If you seee the rails generator template you can see it will blindly take the argument which you send by your commands so if you send rails g migration addOwnerToCats owner_id:your_name it will create the migration file with your_name as a field ....

Comment: I think `references` only works in `create_table` or `change_table`. So yes just do `add_column :cats, :owner_id, :integer` then `add_index :cats, :owner_id`

Comment: @Rajarshi - I assumed as much..

Comment: hmmmm but good try ...can you ask this an new issue in rails main repo so that we can start working  Please follow the link https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/new..thanks

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb the blind template

Comment: This feature is available in Rails 4, it will generate  add_reference :cats, :owner, but in Rails 3, no idea.... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-type-modifiers

Comment: @Bigxiang look he did that `rails g migration AddOwnerToCats owner:references`

Comment: or index add he can try `rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts owner_id:integer:index` but `rails 4`

Comment: @RajarshiDas, In Rails 3 ,I think your last comment is right. In Rails 4, just rails g migration AddOwnerToCats owner:references should be ok.

Comment: is `owner_id:integer:index` the exact same thing as `owner:references`?

Comment: @RajarshiDas - I did the `owner_id:integer:index` and that seems to work perfect, you should make that into an answer

Answer (score 0):

One way, which i can think of, and is a workaround is, simply create the column, and give the join condition in the model. i.e.

```
has_many :x, :class_name => y, :foreign_key => z
```

Comment: This won't be a foreign key in the sense that there's no index on that column

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but as of Rails 5 (and perhaps earlier versions), the [official docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) have been updated:

```
rails generate migration AddOwnerRefToCats owner:references
```

will generate

```
class AddOwnerRefToCats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :cats, :owner, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

You can also add `, index: true` to create an index.